# Use feathers-common-hook's populate in before hook

Tags: javascript, feathersjs, feathers-hook

Is it possible to use populate/fastjoin as before hook?

[image]

The exact need:
I have two services users and user-statuses.

```js
// Models looks like this 
const users = {
    id: number,
    name: string
}

const user-statuses = {
    userId: number,
    status: string
}
```

I want to get all users with status 'invited':

```js
app.service('users').find({
    query: {
        status: 'invited'
    }
})
```

How I need to setup populate/fastjoin if it possible to solve this?

*(I use feathers-sequelize and know about it's include mechanism. It can do this.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No possibility to do it by feathers-common-hook lib, but [joinQuery](https://daddywarbucks.github.io/feathers-fletching/hooks.html#joinquery) from feathers-fletching solve this problem. Correct request with fletching will look like this:

```js
app.service('users').find({
  query: {
    'user_status.status': 'invited'
  }
});
```